# Turtlebot 2, Indigo Installation problem, "Cannot locate rosdep" for turtlebot_stdr, turtlebot_dashboard and turtlebot_gazebo

Tags: turtlebot2, turtlebot, rosdep, turtlebot-gazebo, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm experiencing problems installing turtlebot 2 on indigo in a Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty). I'm following the installation tutorial documented at http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Installation . When installing the workspaces (point 4) I do:

$ mkdir ~/turtlebot

$ cd ~/turtlebot

$ wstool init src -j5 https://raw.github.com/yujinrobot/yujin_tools/master/rosinstalls/indigo/turtlebot.rosinstall source ~/kobuki/devel/setup.bash

$ rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y

the last command fails and I get:

~/turtlebot$ rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:

turtlebot_stdr: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [stdr]

turtlebot_dashboard: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [create_dashboard]

turtlebot_gazebo: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [create_gazebo_plugins]

Has anyone experimented the same problem? any hint?

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194139/turtlebot-2,-indigo-installation-problem,-%22cannot-locate-rosdep%22-for-turtlebot_stdr,-turtlebot_dashboard-and-turtlebot_gazebo/) by [prr](https://answers.ros.org/users/20382/prr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maani](https://answers.ros.org/users/20376/maani/) on 2014-10-07**:
I have the same problem. have you found anyway around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi I get the same error and google it and find this command

> > rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y -r
> > and it is work :)

---

Originally posted by [momar82](https://answers.ros.org/users/14996/momar82/) with karma: 28 on 2014-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maani](https://answers.ros.org/users/20376/maani/) on 2014-10-16**:
That's what I did at the end. it works for now but I still have problem with Kinect, even though Asus xtion pro works well. The option "-r" just ignores the errors and keep installing the required dependencies.